# Makefile: change compiler flags based on CC/CXX/FC values

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, fortran

It seems absurd that there wouldn't already be a question about this, but I can't find one. Anyway, I am writing a makefile, and I just want to have a conditional statement that sets different CFLAGS depending on whether GNU or Intel compilers are being used to compile the program, set by the envrionment variable CC.

Now, there is a section in the GNU make manual on this, and it says to do something like the following:

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_7.html

```
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
  libs=$(libs_for_gcc)
else
  libs=$(normal_libs)
endif
```

(ok setting libraries not flags, but whatever, same idea). Ok fine, but surely this is just an example of how conditionals work, because in practice this is obviously a stupid way to do this. The CC variable can contain all manner of things besides 'gcc' and still be effectively using a GNU C compiler. Even just specifying the absolute path to the compiler in CC will break this example.

So what is the sensible, robust, way to do this? Also, in case it matters, I want to do the same thing for C++ and Fortran compiler choices as well.

Comment: the most sensible and robust way (IMHO) is to use a makefile compiler such as CMake to generate the makefile for you. CMake (and others) is aware of different platforms and toolsets.

Comment: However even with CMake, if you want to set additional compiler flags (or different libs etc.) depending on the compiler, you still need to detect the compiler (normally according to the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID). So you still might not be able to get rid of compiler detection completely (for example, if you want to force "-Wall -Wextra -Werror" with GCC/CLang which other compilers might not recognize). But true, I also prefer to use the CMake if I have the option.

Comment: Yeah CMake is definitely better, however I am actually dealing with some legacy code and I just want to fix up the existing makefile so that it isn't so easily broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that this is not so robust. A more robust way could be to use the findstring command, for example:

```
ifneq (,$(findstring gcc,$(CC)))
  libs=$(libs_for_gcc)
else
  libs=$(normal_libs)
endif
```

Comment: Hmm yeah something like this seems to be at least the next step of improvement :). But is this the best one can do without going to a full autotools/cmake type of system?